# SSMS -- how to load saved queries? My saved .sql file is not finding the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SSMS. This seems simple but I'm finding nothing.

I can open a table and right-click to query the top 1000 rows, then successfully update that query and get the information I want. When I later open the saved query in SSMS and try to run it, it gives me an error: `Invalid object name 'TABLE_NAME'`.

However, if I right-click, select top 1000 rows, and then copy-paste my saved query into that text field, then when I run it that way, it works.

How can I skip the copy-paste step and just open files that run the query successfully the first time?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add `USE [DATEBASE_NAME]` to your saved query.  I'm guessing that your saved query is not using the right database by default.  SSMS also has a toolbar that shows the current database that's selected.  Having that toolbar visible might also make it clear to you which database your query is being run against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSMS , each query window has connection with its own session.

so whenever you open a query , you have to make sure you have connected to the right SQL server instance and It's pointed to the right database

I recommend you always use below command before all your queries:

```
USE [databasename]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please select `database name` from the top or open new query tab by clicking on database from the left panel and paste your query there and execute.